# how to call controller from button click without using ajax mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, reload

I'm new to web programming in general so this is probably a really simple question. I couldn't find anything on the web however.

What I want to do is call my controller with the typed search string and return the results from a database and paginate the results. Right now I am using a function that is called when the button is pressed. The function looks like so:

```
function SubmitSearch() {

    var searchBox = document.getElementById('searchBox');
    var searchButton = document.getElementById('SearchButton');

    $.post("MyController/MyAction/",
    {
        searchString: searchBox.value,
        page: null
    }, function(result) {
        $('#searchResults').html(result);
        searchButton.value = "Search";
    });
}
```

What happens is my controller is called, and my searchResults div is populated with the results and paginated. The user can click any search result returned to view the details.

The problem is when the user clicks the browsers 'back' button, the page returns to the state before the search was entered, and this is because of the ajax call. What I want to do is, call the controller and have the page load like google would. Instead of using a PartialView, I would use a View (my guess).

How would I call the controller and have the page RELOAD with the results. I must be missing something fundamental because this definitely seems like it should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use AJAX then you need to place your text field in a form element on your page, something like:

```
<form action="MyController/MyAction/" method="get">
  <input id="SearchBox" name="SearchBox" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Then in your controller return the view with the list of results.

You probably also want to look into [RESTful](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/12/06/aspnet-mvc-using-restful-architecture/) URLs and the [PRG (Post, Redirect, Get)](http://devlicio.us/blogs/tim_barcz/archive/2008/08/22/prg-pattern-in-the-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx) pattern to maintain the integrity of the back button and enable correct bookmarking of pages etc.

Comment: Thanks, I went with this solution, except I used the MVC way (<% using Html.BeginForm("MyAction","MyController") { %> ....

Answer (score 1):

I think you might actually be looking for an AJAX History library to help when the Back button is pressed rather than altering your app. Take a look at this [blog post](http://codinginparadise.org/weblog/2005/09/ajax-history-libraries.html).

Comment: I would really like to reload the page. In my Action, I have some sloppy coding to take care of the pagination and search pages (I have to call different views based on if the call was ajax or not [my other paginated pages reload the page])

Comment: You main problem is that your example doesn't use Ajax so it's hard to replicate. Your challenge is to get the 'back' action to go back to your controller as if a search had been triggered with both the criteria and the page within the pagination. Doing that with a db on the back end also risks the returned dataset having changed since the original presentation to there's no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Aspx:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm<MyController>(m => m.MyAction(null)) { %> 
    <%= Html.TextBox("q"); %>
<% } %>
// Listing
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(string q)
    {
        var repository; // instance of your repository.

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
        {
            return View(repository.GetAllBlogs());
        }
        return View(repository.SearchBlogs(q));
    }
}
```

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx     please read